# Как правильно соединить телефон и Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, драйвер

недавно скачал Android studio, захотел протестировать простейшую программу на смартфоне.
Смартфон у меня Huawei GR 5 (17 года),у меня Windows 7.Так вот компьютер видит смартфон,все работает,но  Android studio не видит, в sdk manager  установил Google usb drivers,пробовал adb команды(server:kill,start).Заметил что когда смартфон подключен ,Windows видит его как портативное устройство,(там драйвера для MTP),  и ещё не было Android composite adb interface,я захотел установить adb interface:скачал,начал обновлять смартфон,но Windows  не дал его обновить,мол найдено подходящее по:этот самый MTP драйвер.Также,всякие adbbin не работают.Полагаюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Смартфон в режим разработчика переведён?

Comment: Да.Первым делом

Comment: скачайте (или посмотрите по указанному пути в SDK) USB драйвер https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Comment: Я читал,как я думаю,все дело в MTP драйвере,он не даёт установить другие драйвера

Comment: После многочасовых манипуляции с драйверами и устройствами,получилось.Спасибо всем за советы

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось,я просто не включал отладку usb, спасибо всем.